# How to catch a new item selection in a class that derives CComboBox

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a class that derives `CComboBox` and I want it to handle internally when the user selects another item. I know that I can catch the selection  in the parent control with `ON_CBN_SELCHANGE`, but I want to handle the selection change within the combobox itself, so that I can use the private implementation details of my own derived combobox class to interpret the new selection.

Is this possible and how I can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In header:

```
afx_msg LRESULT OnSelchange();
```

in cpp file:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CComboBoxExt, CComboBox)
ON_CONTROL_REFLECT_EX(CBN_SELCHANGE, OnSelchange)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

LRESULT CComboBoxExt::OnSelchange() 
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

// do your job ...

return Default();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to make the method return BOOL in order to make this work, but it works exactly as I need now.